# I can't get the same answer when using both rectangular and cylindrical coordinates for this triple integral. Which is right?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

When I solve this triple integral problem with rectangular coordinates I get a different answer than with cylindrical coordinates. Which one is correct? Can you spot my mistake? Perhaps its with the cylindrical limits? It seems like I've missed a $1/2$ somewhere.

**Problem:**
Find $\iiint_E yz \space dV$ where E lies above the plane $z = 0$, below the plane $z = y$, and inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=9$.

**Solution with rectangular coordinates:**

$$
E={(x,y,z)|-3 \leq x \leq 3;0 \leq y \leq \sqrt{9-x^2};0 \leq z \leq y }
$$

$$\int_{-3}^{3} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} \int_{0}^{y} yz \space dV$$
$$\int_{-3}^{3} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} \int_{0}^{y} yz \space dzdydx$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{-3}^{3} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} y\bigr[z^2 \bigr]_{0}^{y} dydx$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{-3}^{3} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} y^3 dydx$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{-3}^{3} \frac{1}{4}\bigr[y^4 \bigr]_{0}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} dx$$

$$\frac{1}{8} \int_{-3}^{3} (9-x^2)^2 dx$$
$$\frac{1}{8} \int_{-3}^{3} (81-18x^2+x^4) dx$$

$$\frac{1}{8} \biggr[(81x-6x^3+\frac{1}{5}x^5) \biggr]_{-3}^{3} $$

$$ \frac{1}{8}\bigr[(81(3)-6(3^3)+\frac{3^5}{5})-(-81(3)+6(3^3)-\frac{3^5}{5})\bigr] $$
$$ \frac{1}{8}\bigr[2(81(3))-2(6)(3^3)+2\frac{3^5}{5})\bigr] $$

$$ = -32.4 $$

**Solution with cylindrical coordinates**

Using substitutions: $y=rsin\theta$ and $r^2=x^2+y^2$

$$E = { (\theta,r,z) | 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi ; 0 \leq r \leq 3 ; 0 \leq z \leq rsin\theta } $$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{rsin\theta} rsin\theta z \space r dz dr d\theta$$
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{rsin\theta} r^2z sin\theta \space dzdrd\theta$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{3} r^2sin\theta \bigr[z^2\bigr]_{0}^{rsin\theta} drd\theta$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{3} r^4sin^3\theta \space drd\theta$$

$$\frac{1}{10} \int_{0}^{\pi} sin^3\theta \biggr[r^5\biggr]_{0}^{3} \space d\theta$$

$$\frac{3^5}{10} \int_{0}^{\pi} sin^3\theta \space d\theta$$

$$\frac{3^5}{10} \int_{0}^{\pi} sin\theta (1-cos^2\theta) \space d\theta$$
$$\frac{3^5}{10} \int_{0}^{\pi} sin\theta d\theta - \int_{0}^{\pi} sin\theta cos^2\theta \space d\theta$$

With u-substitution $u=cos\theta$, $du=-sin\theta$:
$$\frac{3^5}{10} \bigr[ cos\theta \bigr]_{0}^{\pi} - \frac{3^5}{10} \int u^2 \space d\theta$$

$$\frac{3^5}{10} \bigr[ cos\theta + \frac{1}{3} cos^3\theta \bigr]_{0}^{\pi} $$

$$\frac{3^5}{10} \bigr[ (-1 + \frac{1}{3}(-1)) - (1 + \frac{1}{3} (1)) \bigr] $$

$$\frac{3^5}{10} \bigr[2(-1) + 2(-\frac{1}{3}) \bigr] $$

$$=\frac{3^5}{10}\frac{-8}{3}=-64.8$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the answer can't possibly be negative, since the integrand $yz$ is nonnegative in the region $E$. The integral $\frac18 \int_{-3}^3 (9-x^2)^2 dx$ equals $+32.4$, not $-32.4$.

Secondly, there's a sign error in the last antiderivative in the second calculation; it should be $-\cos\theta + \frac13 \cos^3 \theta$.